# C# Get "value" from an xml file using xpath

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

I want to print the "value" `Computer` into my console. but I'm unable to find proper resources as I don't know the terminology that is needed to search, like nodes, child, values, ecc..

My current code:

```cs
XDocument xml = XDocument.Load(Localization);
XElement pattern = xml.XPathSelectElement("/resources/string[@key=\"Example\"]");
```

Xml:

```xml
<resources xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <string key="Example">Computer</string>
</resources>
```

What can I do to print that value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting an `XElement` object from `xml.XPathSelectElement()`. In The `XElement` class, there is a property called `Value` which will return the enclosing text (string) within an element.

The following code will print out what you desired:

```cs
XDocument xml = XDocument.Load(Localization);
XElement pattern = xml.XPathSelectElement("/resources/string[@key=\"Example\"]");

Console.WriteLine(pattern.Value);
```

Console output:

```
Computer
```

## Terminology

XML/HTML can be viewed as a tree of nodes (element) and children of nodes.

[image]

Attribution: [W3 Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp)

- `Document` is the parent of `Root Element`
- `Root Element` is a child of `Document`
- The ancestors of `<head>` are `<html>` and `Document` (think family tree)
- The descendants of `Document` are all the children nodes including nested children
- Siblings are nodes on the same level. For example, `<head>` is a sibling to `<body>`

The `XElement` class allows you to traverse other nodes that are related to the current node.

XPath allows you to easily traverse the XML tree using a string.

## XElement Documentation

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xelement?view=net-7.0

Answer (score 0):

You do not need xpath with xml linq.  Use a dictionary to get all key values

```
           XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
            Dictionary<string, string> dict = doc.Descendants("string")
                .GroupBy(x => (string)x.Attribute("key"), y => (string)y)
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.FirstOrDefault());
```